# javascript determine of firebug

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cross-browser, firebug, mozilla

I want to ask people to disable firebug. How to determine that they have installed firebug? And so it was a cross-browser and determined in Chrome, Mozilla and IE8 +

Comment: This is **evil**.

Comment: Firebug runs only on Firefox. Others only have a sort of something that's not really firebug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two steps:

1. if `window.console` exists, then Firebug might be installed. This might not be true, since `window.console` might also indicate that Chrome's console is enabled.
2. if step 1. returns an object, check if `console.firebug` returns anything. If it does, it will be Firebug's version number.

Now you know how to see if Firebug is installed, but you can't force your user do disable it. Try logging in to Gmail with Firebug enabled and they show you a warning that having it enabled might lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 4):

easy:

```
if(window.console && window.console.firebug) alert("I caught a firebug");
```

edit: I don't see any reason to ask people disable it, unless you have a strong performance issue like gmail.

edit2: I've read your question again. If you also want to check for firefly and chrome console, just check for window.console

*important* edit3: firebug 1.9 doesn't add window.console.firebug anymore. don't know since which version this is the case.

Comment: in the window.onload function?

Comment: but my mozilla (3.6.13) and firebug doesn't determined!

Comment: yes, that's what I would do. I mean, probably you don't need to wait for the document load as the console is independent of document.